# I don't know why my structs below are not being set

Tags: c, struct

goodsubject-lm:chap6 varunvb$ cat linkedlists.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct island {
  char *name;
  char *opens;
  char *closes;
  struct island *next;
} island;

island amity = {"Amity", "09:00", "17:00", NULL};
island craggy = {"Craggy", "09:00", "18:00", NULL};
island isla_nublar = {"Shutter", "09:00", "19:00", NULL};
island skull = {"Skull", "09:00", "20:00", NULL};
island shutter = {"Shutter", "09:00", ":21:00", NULL};
amity.next = &craggy;
craggy.next = &isla_nublar;
isla_nublar.next = &skull;
skull.next = &shutter;

void display (island *start) {

  island *i = start;

  for (; i != NULL; i == i->next) {
     printf ("Name: %s\nOpens: %s\ncloses: %s\n", i->name, i->opens, i->closes);
     }
}

int main ()
{
 display (&amity);
 display (&craggy);
 display (&isla_nublar);
 display (&skull);
 return 0;
}
```

The errors I get are as below.

```
linkedlists.c:15:1: error: unknown type name 'amity'
amity.next = &craggy;
^
linkedlists.c:15:6: error: expected identifier or '('
amity.next = &craggy;
     ^
linkedlists.c:16:1: error: unknown type name 'craggy'
craggy.next = &isla_nublar;
^
linkedlists.c:16:7: error: expected identifier or '('
craggy.next = &isla_nublar;
      ^
linkedlists.c:17:1: error: unknown type name 'isla_nublar'
isla_nublar.next = &skull;
^
linkedlists.c:17:12: error: expected identifier or '('
isla_nublar.next = &skull;
           ^
linkedlists.c:18:1: error: unknown type name 'skull'
skull.next = &shutter;
^
linkedlists.c:18:6: error: expected identifier or '('
skull.next = &shutter;
     ^
linkedlists.c:24:23: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
  for (; i != NULL; i == i->next) {
                    ~~^~~~~~~~~~
linkedlists.c:24:23: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
  for (; i != NULL; i == i->next) {
                      ^~
                      =
1 warning and 8 errors generated.
```

Comment: You can initialise variables at global scope, i.e. ouside functions, but you can't have statements like `amity.next = &craggy;`; these must be in a function body, between the curly braces. Move the statements (and possibly also the data definitions) into `main`.

Comment: That said, 1) the `==` in for loop increment condition should be `=` 2) one call to `display()` will print all the values..

Comment: You will also want `shutter.next = NULL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (; i != NULL; i == i->next) {`

I think you meant `i = i->next`. Your loop is either infinite or never run.

For your errors, you should not use globals and instead create and link your elements inside your code. At least move your `x.next = &y` statements into your main, as M Oehm commented.

You could have an island factory function that allocates a pointer to `island` and fills it, then returns it.

For example:

```
island *add_island(island *begin, char *name, char *opens, char *closes)
{
  island *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));

  if (new == NULL)
  {
    printf("Malloc error in add_island");
    return NULL;
  }
  new->name = name;
  new->opens = opens;
  new->closes = closes;
  new->next = begin;

  return new;
}

int main(void)
{
  island *list = add_island(NULL, "last island", "12:00", "02:00");
  list = add_island(list, "first island", "20:00", "10:00");
  display(list);
}
```

`add_island` acts as a push into the list given.

Comment: @MOehm Awesome! I moved the statements with in main and worked like a charm.

Comment: you're right. That's an '=' assignment. Thanks guys!

Comment: Also in the for loop code, i have to use a semi colon in the beginning, do you know why that is ? for (; i != NULL; i == i->next) @Eregrith

Comment: @Ani It's the syntax of the `for` construct. If you don't know that I suggest you spend some time reviewing it as it is a basic construct and it's very useful. To summarize it's `for (initialize ; check ; progress)`, so you could have written `for (island *i = start; i != NULL; i == i->next)` instead (be wary as the variable `i` will only be defined *inside* the `for` this way)